# Freezing OS X Screen in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have two methods that modify the display of the screen. Is there a way to freeze the screen until the second method is called?

```
// I want to freeze the screen here
updateDisplay1(); // Change in display doesn't take effect until screen is unfrozen
updateDisplay2();
// Unfreeze screen here
```

In Excel VBA this would be something like screenUpdating = FALSE. Is there a similar function in Cocoa?

One possible way is to take screenshot:

```
// Take screenshot of the screen
// Display the screenshot image in front of the screen
updateDisplay1(); // Change is not visible
updateDisplay2();
// Remove screenshot image
```

But I'm afraid this is slow and takes up a lot of memory. Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: Your topic is confusing and misleading.  If you say 'the display of the screen,' it should occur to most that you are talking about the monitor screen.

Comment: My English is not very good, sorry about that. But my question is very easy to understand, isn't it? I just want to know how to freeze what is displayed on the screen.

Comment: There is a function `NSDisableScreenUpdates`, but it only works on windows owned by your process.  So if you are using Accessibility to control another process, that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

What screen are you talking about?

Standard Cocoa behaviour is:

1. you update the properties of the various views you are interested in;
2. each of those will make a call to its own `setNeedsDisplayInRect`. As a result of those calls, a redraw will be scheduled on the run loop;
3. once you've finished doing all of your updates, the run loop will be able to move onto its next item;
4. eventually it'll reach the redraw it scheduled and will make appropriate `drawRect` calls to appropriate views.

So all view changes that you make in response to an action are automatically atomic. You have to go significantly out of your own way to create a partial update.

Comment: I'm using the Accessibility API to resize and reposition windows. There's no way to change the size and the position simultaneously. The screen is updated twice (the window is resized first and then repositioned).

Comment: Please post the calls in the Accessibility API that you are using; that is essential information to the question!  You can't expect people to read your mind.

Comment: I was expecting an answer that freezes the screen regardless of what happens when the screen is frozen, a call to Accessibility API or whatever. Anyway the call is AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue (myAXWindowElement, kAXPositionAttribute, myTargetPosition)

Answer (score 0):

taking screenshots with CGWindowListCreateImage takes a few milliseconds and uses roughly any memory. it's usually done directly in the graphic card.

give it a try and measure before doing any performance assumptions:-)

Comment: I tried that and encountered a problem. So the sequence is: (1) get a screenshot, (2) put the screenshot image covering the screen, (3) perform the first screen update, (4) perform the second screen update, (5) remove the screenshot image. But it appears that step (2) is too slow so that when I ran the code the order looks like 1-3-4-2-5. Is there a way to prevent (3) and (4) from running before (2) finishes?

Comment: I managed to make it work after several trials and errors. It's still a little slow for my purpose, but at least it works.

Comment: @user5498580 did this answer help you? if yes, would you like to accept it using the green checkmark left to my answer?